# Set status bar icon names

Tags: android, icons, manifest, statusbar

I'm about to publish my first application. I created all the necessary icons, in my case the launcher icons and the status icons (which I only created for my app next versions updates).

But I am wondering where the status icons names are set. I mean, the launcher icon name is set in the Manifest file this way :

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

so is there a similar place to set the status icon name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you explicitly set the icon when you make a notification. So:

```
int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
CharSequence tickerText = "Your Text";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
```

This was taken directly from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to do any forced notification, I just want the status bar to load my status icon when an update of my app will be launched. In this case how can set the status bar name?

Comment: Like when you are notified that some apps updates are available. Honestly, until a few hours ago, I thought that the status icons were made for only this purpose.

Comment: Well, I think you are talking about the default way in which Android notifies the user of app updates. This is a notification specific to the Market application and therefore is controlled only by that application. If you want to notify the user that there is another version of your application to download you can do one of two things. Let the Market notify the user they have updated apps to download and install or send a Cloud to Device Message that is caught by your application that either notifies them via the notification status bar or a dialog that pops up the next time they enter the app

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I don't wanna do any complicated thing. I just want the Android Market App to use my icon status bar when it will notify automatically that a new version of my app is available. I thought it would be just to create the icon and leave them in a folder with a specific name but it seems it doesn't work this way. Why is not it so? Which icon the Android Market App will then use for the notification???

Comment: Forget about this thread. There is absolutely no app icon in the update notifications. Sorry for the confusion.